# Fatal: Reference is not a Tree:

Tags: django

I'm trying to do the bookmarks project of "Antonio Mele - Django 4 by example" and when I get to this command in the shell `pip install git+https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions.git@25a41d8a3ecb24c009c5f4cac6010a091a3c91c8` I get the error

```
Collecting git+https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions.git@25a41d8a3ecb24c009c5f4cac6010a091a3c91c8
  Cloning https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions.git (to revision 25a41d8a3ecb24c009c5f4cac6010a091a3c91c8) to c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\temp\pip-req-build-sm2evy1_
  Running command git clone -q https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions.git 'C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-sm2evy1_'
  Running command git checkout -q 25a41d8a3ecb24c009c5f4cac6010a091a3c91c8
  fatal: reference is not a tree: 25a41d8a3ecb24c009c5f4cac6010a091a3c91c8
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 128: git checkout -q 25a41d8a3ecb24c009c5f4cac6010a091a3c91c8 Check the logs for full command output.
```

Does anyone know why this happens?
Note: `pip install git+https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-app-django.git@20fabcd7bd9a8a41910bc5c8ed1bd6ef2263b328` worked with no problem but this one just doesn't work

Comment: You need to specify the package name, so:

Comment: `pip install 'django-extensions@git+https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions.git@25a41d8a3ecb24c009c5f4cac6010a091a3c91c8'`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I tried this and it said `Requirement already satisfied`, does that mean it's been installed?

Comment: normally yes. Unless you already install `django-extensions` for example without a reference to the repository. In that case you first uninstall the installed version.